# Bootstrap 4 how to add margin to element inside a col?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have some span elements inside a col:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <span class="myClass">some text</span>
        <span class="myClass">some text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

myClass elements have some padding:

```
.myClass{
  background: #ecedea;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Because there is multiple span elements in the first col, a new line is being created. My problem is because of the padding I have some overlay between my spans in the first line and my spans in the second line:

[image]

I tried to add some margin-top to myClass but it didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`span` doesn't have margin because it's an `inline` element.

You can fix the CSS like this:

```
.myClass{
  background: #ecedea;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

OR, you can use Bootstrap 4 [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) and avoid the extra CSS:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <span class="bg-light d-inline-block p-2 mr-3">some text</span>
        <span class="bg-light d-inline-block p-2 mr-3">some text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/jKCFqBb92J